# how to cross compile for spark2 and spark3 with sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

In my program, I need to develop programs for both Spark2 and Spark3 simultaneously.
So I need to compile twice.Current approach is to use a shell script, just like:

```bash
./gradlew package -Pscala=2.11.8 -Pspark=2.3.2
./gradlew package -Pscala=2.12.8 -Pspark=3.3.1
```

I want to migrate to SBT. Can it be completed through cross compilation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SBT's cross compilation](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Cross-Build.html) is primarily meant for cross compiling against multiple Scala versions.

If each version of Spark you want to compile with relates to a single Scala version, you could use SBT cross compilation for that as a kind of workaround.

---

A better solution is probably to use SBT features of ["multi modules"](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Multi-Project.html) and have a module for each Spark version (optionally cross compiled to multiple Scala versions) sharing all (or some) source code + different libraries versions if needed.

There are many ways to implement this, if you go this way and encounter issues, post a specific question here and we'll help.

There's also the [sbt-project-matrix](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-projectmatrix#parallel-cross-library-building) plugin which can simplify a bit the submodules for you and also handle cross compilation but in a different way than the SBT default one.